# Passport.js returns unauthorized on all requests, or authorizes all regardless the token

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, jwt, passport.js

My Passsport.js functions fail to authenticate users.

In this form it returns "unauthorized" for all requests:

```
import passport from 'passport'
import passportJWT from 'passport-jwt'
import userModel from '../user/user.model'
import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express'

export default class PassportController{

    static async setup(app: express.Application){
        const JWTStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy
        const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt
        const config = {
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
            issuer: 'DepoApp',
            
        }

        passport.use(userModel.createStrategy())
        passport.use(new JWTStrategy(
            config, 
            (payload, done) => {
                userModel.findOne({_id: payload.id}, (err:any, user:any) => {
                    if(err) {
                        return done(err, false)
                    }
                    else if(user){
                        return done(null, user)
                    }
                    else{
                        return done(null, false)
                    }
                })
            }
        ))
    }

    static async auth(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction){
        await passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false})(req, res, next)
    }
}
```

When i change `auth` method to form below, it authorizes all users regardless their token:

```
static async auth(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction){
        await passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false})
        next()
    }
```

I figure that this is caused by inproper form of middleware `auth`, so please help me to configure it.

In `index.ts` i simply call `PassportController.setup()`

Note #1: I am not using sessions

Note #2: I am using _id as default key, user model doesn't have username field, as organization already has a database of user IDs. User model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'
import Permits from './permits.enum'
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose'

const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String},                        //album number (Organisation specific ID)
    first_name: {type: String, required: true},
    last_name: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, required: true},
    mail: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, trim: true, unique: true},
    permits: [{type: String, enum: Permits, default: []}],
},
{
    collection: 'users',
    timestamps: true,
})

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: '_id'})
const userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default userModel
```

I have tried changing `auth` method in various ways, as described above. I also tried changing `JWTStrategy()` contents, surprisingly `console.log(payload)` does not print anything (It's just empty, as if function was never called).

In similar question here there is a problem with routes, but in my case everything is as it's supposed to be.

routes:

```
this.app.route('/api/depo')
        .get(PassportController.auth, DepoController.getAll)
        .post(PassportController.auth, DepoController.post)
        
this.app.route('/api/depo/:id')
        .get(PassportController.auth, DepoController.getById)
        .patch(PassportController.auth, DepoController.patchById)
        .delete(PassportController.auth, DepoController.deleteById)


this.app.route('/api/no-gdpr/depo/')
        .get(DepoController.getAllNoGDPR)

this.app.route('/api/no-gdpr/depo/:id')
        .get(DepoController.getOneNoGDPR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved!

There were two main errors that caused this situation.

1. the JWT token didn't have `issuer` property, so the entire strategy was skipped, as `passport.js` already rejected the request. That's why i removed issuer field form `config`:

```
const config = {
     jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
     secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
}
```

Then another error occoured - `mongoose` v. 5.* revoked callbacks from `findOne()` method. For this reason I had to refactor the Strategy callback a little bit:

```
const JWTstrategy = new passportJWT.Strategy(
    config, 
    (payload, done) => {
        var user
        try{
            user = userModel.findOne({_id: payload.user._id})
        }catch(err){
            return done(err, false)
        }
        if(user){
            return done(null, user)
        }
        else{
            return done(null, false)
        }
    }
)
```

So now the entire `setup` function looks like this:

```
    static async setup() {

      const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt

      const config = {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      }

      const JWTstrategy = new passportJWT.Strategy(
        config,
        (payload, done) => {
          var user
          try {
            user = userModel.findOne({
              _id: payload.user._id
            })
          } catch (err) {
            return done(err, false)
          }
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            return done(null, false)
          }
        }
      )


      passport.use(userModel.createStrategy())
      passport.use('jwt', JWTstrategy)

      console.log('[PASSPORT]: setup finished.')
    }
```